# OpenMP time and clock() give two different results

Tags: c, openmp

I have sequential code to parallelize via OpenMP. I have put in the corresponding pragmas and tested it. I measure the performance gain by checking the time spent in the main function.

The weird thing is the elapsed time calculated via `cpu_time()` and `omp_get_wtime()` is different. Why?

The elapsed time according to `cpu_time()` is similar to the sequential time.

Before computation starts:

```
ctime1_ = cpu_time();
#ifdef _OPENMP
ctime1 = omp_get_wtime();
#endif
```

After computation ends:

```
ctime2_ = cpu_time();
#ifdef _OPENMP
ctime2 = omp_get_wtime();
#endif
```

cpu_time() function definition:

```
double cpu_time(void)
{
  double value;
  value = (double) clock () / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  return value;
}
```

Printing result:

```
printf("%f - %f seconds.\n", ctime2 - ctime1, ctime2_ - ctime1_);
```

Sample result:

```
7.009537 - 11.575277 seconds.
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `clock` function measures cpu time, the time you spend actively on the CPU, the OMP function measures the time as it has passed during execution, two completely different things.

Your process seems to be blocked in waiting somewhere.

Comment: On Windows, `clock()` actually measures wall time.

Comment: @Mysticial, again, they seem to follow there own mood, instead of the standard. The standard says: *The clock function returns the implementation’s best approximation to the processor time used by the program since the beginning of an implementation-defined era related only to the program invocation.*

Comment: @JensGustedt Sounds like they follow the standard. *The implementation's best approximation* just seems to be the wall time kek

Answer (score 12):

What you observe is a perfectly valid result for any parallel application - the combined *CPU time* of all threads as returned by `clock()` is usually more than the *wallclock time* measured by `omp_get_wtime()` except if your application mostly sleeps or waits.

Answer (score 6):

The `clock()` function returns *CPU* time, not *wall* time. Instead, use [`gettimeofday()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday).