# Uncertain about correctness of timekeeping for parallel programs with posix threads and openMP

Tags: c, parallel-processing, pthreads, openmp, benchmarking

I am trying to benchmark three functions in C for numerical Integration of PI as an exercise for usage of threads.
The first is sequential, the second is with posix threads and the third is with openMP.

My benchmark output shows that the sequential function is the fastest, but that absolutely doesn't feel right. It feels almost half as fast, but the output shows that it's double as fast.

Here is my code:

```
// gcc -pthread -fopenmp benchmark.c -o benchmark -Wall -lm

#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#define STEPS 1000000000      // Number of steps for numerical integration
#define STEP_SIZE  1.0/STEPS  // Size of a step
#define ST  (0.5) * STEP_SIZE // Starting size of the function
#define NUM_THREADS 4         // Number of Threads

/**
 * This Struct represents a posix thread.
 * pthread_create() takes this struct as an argument.
 * @see pthread_pi()
 */
typedef struct _pthread_arg
{
  int thread_id; // ID of the Thread
  double val; // Integral of the Thread
} pthread_arg;

/**
 * This Function measures the time of a function.
 */
void benchmark(double f())
{
  double pi;
  clock_t start, end;
  double time_elapsed;

  start = clock();
  pi = (f());
  end = clock();

  time_elapsed = ((double)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("Computed PI = %.13f \n", pi);
  printf("Difference to Reference is %.13f \n", M_PI - pi);
  printf("time elapsed:%f\n", time_elapsed);
}

/**
 * This Function calculates the value of PI with numerical Integration
 * sequentially.
 */
double sequential_pi()
{
  double step_size = 1.0/STEPS, t = 0.5 * step_size, sum = 0;

  while (t < 1.0)
  {
    sum += sqrt(1 - t * t) * step_size;
    t += step_size;
  }
  return sum * 4;
}

/**
 * pthread_create() takes this function as an argument.
 * @see pthread_pi()
 */
void* pthread_calc_pi(void* ptr)
{
  pthread_arg* arg;
  arg = (pthread_arg*) ptr;
  double t;
  double val;
  int thread_id;
  int p; // left intervalboundary
  int q; // right intervalboundary
  int i;

  thread_id = arg->thread_id;
  p = STEPS / NUM_THREADS * thread_id;
  q = STEPS / NUM_THREADS * (thread_id + 1);

  t = ST + STEP_SIZE * p;

  for(i = p; i < q; i++)
  {
    val += sqrt(1 - t * t) * STEP_SIZE;
    t += STEP_SIZE;
  }
  arg->val = val;

  pthread_exit(0);

}

/**
 * This Function calculates the value of PI with numerical Integration with
 * Posix Threads.
 */
double pthread_pi()
{
  double pi;
  int i;
  pthread_t* thread;
  pthread_arg* args;

  thread = malloc(NUM_THREADS * sizeof(pthread_t));
  args = malloc(NUM_THREADS * sizeof(pthread_arg));

  // Initialisation and creation of Threads
  for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
  {
    args[i].thread_id = i;
    pthread_create(&(thread[i]), NULL, &pthread_calc_pi, (void*) &args[i]);
  }
  // Synchronisation of threads and reduction of val
  for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
  {
    pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
    pi += args[i].val;
  }

  return pi * 4;
}

/**
 * This Function calculates the value of PI with numerical Integration with
 * openMP.
 */
double openMP_pi()
{
  int i;
  double pi = 0;
  int p; // left intervalboundary
  int q; // right intervalboundary
  int j;
  double t;

  omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);

  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:pi) private(p,q,t,j)
  for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
  {
    p = STEPS / NUM_THREADS * i;
    q = STEPS / NUM_THREADS * (i + 1);

    t = ST + STEP_SIZE * p;

    for(j = p; j < q; j++)
    {
      pi += sqrt (1 - t * t) * STEP_SIZE;
      t += STEP_SIZE;
    }
  }
  return pi * 4;
}

int main()
{
  printf("\npthread:\n");
  benchmark(&pthread_pi);
  printf("\nopenMP:\n");
  benchmark(&openMP_pi);
  printf("\nsequential:\n");
  benchmark(&sequential_pi);

  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

here is the output:

```
pthread:
Computed PI = 3.1415926680606 
Difference to Reference is -0.0000000144708 
time elapsed:8.774720

openMP:
Computed PI = 3.1415926680606 
Difference to Reference is -0.0000000144708 
time elapsed:8.783519

sequential:
Computed PI = 3.1415926636781 
Difference to Reference is -0.0000000100883 
time elapsed:4.235619
```

Comment: Just one -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673732/openmp-time-and-clock-calculates-two-different-results -- of the Qs and As covering the issue of using `clock` to measure execution time of OpenMP programs.  In a nutshell -- don't.

Comment: Instead of `malloc`, you could just use a C99 VLA like `pthread_arg args[NUM_THREADS];`.  Actually, with NUM_THREADS being a compile-time constant, it's not even a variable-length array.  Anyway, this is simpler syntax than using `malloc` + `free` and has basically no downside because the number of threads is never going to be more than 1000 or so in an extreme case.

Comment: Also, you can run a calculation in the main thread, so you only need to start `NUM_THREADS-1` *extra* threads.

Comment: The ratio of time interval by clock() to one calculated from omp_get_wtime() may work to indicate the average number of threads. The importance of this is overrated.